# Adding Company Logo/Image in Header with Lightning Design System

Tags: lightning, lightning-design-system, header

I would like to create a VF page with Lightning Design System and I would like to add custom image at Company logo in the header section of the page. I would like to know is it possible with Lightning Design system? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible, put logo in static resource and use URLFOR

Comment: ok. Let me try this out.